# how to pass where in clause values in stored procedure in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a procedure which takes parameter as a string in comma seperated format like "Saved,In Progress".  Below procedure is working fine with on one status like "Saved".  but not working with comma seprated values

```
create or replace PROCEDURE get_Sample_request (
    in_request_status IN VARCHAR2,
     out_cursor        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
    sql_qry     VARCHAR2 (150);
    emp_tot     NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
    OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT * from user_requests where request_status in (in_request_status);



END get_Sample_request;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LIKE`:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE get_Sample_request (
    in_request_status IN VARCHAR2,
     out_cursor        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
    sql_qry     VARCHAR2 (150);
    emp_tot     NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
    OPEN out_cursor FOR
      SELECT *
      FROM   user_requests
      WHERE  ',' || in_request_status || ',' LIKE '%,' || request_status || ',%';
END get_Sample_request;
/
```

Or, pass in a collection:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE get_Sample_request (
    in_request_status IN  SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST,
     out_cursor       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
    sql_qry     VARCHAR2 (150);
    emp_tot     NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
    OPEN out_cursor FOR
      SELECT *
      FROM   user_requests
      WHERE  request_status IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(in_request_status));
END get_Sample_request;
/
```

Or, split the string (slower):

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE get_Sample_request (
    in_request_status IN  VARCHAR2,
     out_cursor       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
    sql_qry     VARCHAR2 (150);
    emp_tot     NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
    OPEN out_cursor FOR
      SELECT *
      FROM   user_requests
      WHERE  request_status IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(in_request_status, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                                FROM   DUAL
                                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(in_request_status, '[^,]+'));
END get_Sample_request;
/
```

Comment: Hey it was easy , Actually  I am completly new to sql i was searching solution similar like mongoDB .Thanks a  lot